# API end point testing using behave

Tags: python, rest, web-api-testing, python-behave

I have a django rest API end point login which takes username and password in form of json object as below.

```
   {
      username: email,
      password: password,
   }
```

and returns a json object containing a token

```
{
   token : 0234jh324234j2hiy342
}
```

Now i want to write a test in behave. I have following feature file.

```
Feature: Login User
  By providing different credentials we check if our login API end point is working as expected or not

  Scenario: Login User by Providing Authentication Credentials
    Given I provide user authentication credentials
    Then I must get a reponse with status code 200 and a jSon object with token
```

and following is my auth.py file

```
from behave import *
import requests
import json


@given('I have user authentication credentials')
def set_impl(context):
    url = 'https://example.com/v1/login'
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    body = {
        "username": "xyz@email.com",
        "password": "abcdef123",
    }


@when('I make an http post call')
def step_impl(context):
    context.res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)


@then('I must get a reponse with status code 200 and a jSon object with token')
def step_impl(context):
    assert context.res.status == 200
```

I am unable to access the url, header and body from @given decorator in @when decorator. And how can i check the json in response against my expected json.

Comment: Add everything you need in a later step to the context.

Comment: It is also a good idea to have a clause like `The response has a key {key} with value {value}.` which can be reused.

Answer (score 2):

Per @KlausD.'s suggestion, you should add your variables to the behave's `context` object. I've edited your code to add your variables as the `context` object's attributes.

```
from behave import *
import requests
import json


@given('I have user authentication credentials')
def set_impl(context):
    context.url = 'https://example.com/v1/login'
    context.headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    context.body = {
        "username": "xyz@email.com",
        "password": "abcdef123",
    }


@when('I make an http post call')
def step_impl(context):
    context.res = requests.post(context.url, data=json.dumps(context.body), headers=context.headers)


@then('I must get a reponse with status code 200 and a jSon object with token')
def step_impl(context):
    assert context.res.status == 200
```

As for checking the JSON in your response against your expected JSON...

1. Check out the `requests` package's `response` object [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/api/#requests.Response) to find out how to get the `response` object's attributes.
2. Open your own expected JSON file via `open()`, grab the value that corresponds to the `token` key, and do an `assert expectedToken == responseToken`, or something of that sort.